# Raster terrain analysis on QGIS 2.0.1 - No curvature analysis?

Tags: qgis, curvature

I need to perform a curvature analysis on a DEM. I've found this tutorial

http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/48-quantum-gis-qgis-raster-based-terrain-analysis-techniques.html

that mentions a "Total curvature analysis" on the Raster terrain analysis plugin. However I've been unable to find that option in the plugin's menu. I am relatively new to QGIS, so I may be missing something, or has that function been discontinued?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Processing Toolbox and you have

[image]

Comment: You have to have SAGA installed and linked to QGIS for this to work. Would be nice to include instructions on how to do that here.

Comment: [Configuring external applications](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html)